# "Extend" webpages to fit a sticky footer

Tags: javascript, css, plugins, iframe

I'm building a plugin that injects an HTML iframe "toolbar" onto the bottom of every web page.  I've achieved "sticky footer" behavior by injecting the following:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" noresize="noresize" src="http://example.com/toolbar.html" style="position:fixed; background:transparent; width:100%; height: 33px; padding:0; bottom: 0px; z-index: 2px;"></iframe>
```

However, this iframe overlaps the bottom 30 pixels of a web page.    What I'm looking for is how to "extend" each web page 30 pixels so that our bar has all the behavior of a sticky footer (it's always present at the bottom of the screen), but a user can still scroll to the bottom of a website and see the bottom-most content of that website.  (Without using traditional frames, which have caused other problems.)

**Additional Info**

[Stumble Upon for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/kcahibnffhnnjcedflmchmokndkjnhpg) has achieve this behavior at the top of the window (i.e., the Stumble Upon Bar "pushes" content down instead of overlapping it.)

Comment: Interesting question, but unless Chrome itself supports some tricks that let an extension modify the window layout I don't see how this can be done, and least if you expect it to *always* work. Lots of layouts expect to have complete control from the `<body>` tag on down.

Comment: can you margin-top to 33px? I know iframes are a pain to style...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>I would add a `padding-bottom:33px` to the body.</strike>

**update**

The above answer will not work if both `html` and `body` tags have `height:100%;`

---

**solution**

scratch the body technique and do.

```
html{
  height:auto!important;
  height:100%;
  min-height:100%;
  padding-bottom:33px;
}
```

i can't think of a scenario where this would mess anything up.

Comment: Would that not just add a 33px padding to the bottom of the content, not the window? I may be wrong here, but doesn't the OP want a 'bar' stuck to the bottom of the window?

Comment: @Jam, the OP has used `position:fixed`, `height:33px` and `bottom:0px` for the iframe, so it is always stuck at the bottom of the window. When adding `padding-bottom:33px` to the `body` we in effect give it 33 more pixels of scroll, allowing the content that was hidden by the toolbar to become visible. Because under the toolbar, it will now will be the 33 pixels of padding.

Comment: @Gaby, thank you for your answer!  You're right about `height: 100%` ... I'd love to hear if there is a solution to that as well.

Comment: @Emile, looks like a bug (*but it is consistent across all browsers so i cant really understand it*). If you wanted it to be on top, and use `padding-top` then it works even for 100% heights. pretty weird if you ask me ..

Comment: Wow @Gaby!  Thank you!  I wish you had more up votes for this answer...it works perfectly in all browsers!

Comment: @Emile, glad we solved it .. i think i will be using it too :)